# Should I update to sql server 2008 sp2 before restoring the db's or do the update after?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-vm

I'm making a move from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2 (Azure VM) as part of a hosting provider switch (from MyHosting to Azure). Should I update the VM to R2 SP2 before restoring the db's or do the update after or don't even do the update?

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion: if you can I would push to 2012 or 2014 rather than just to 2008r2 (especially if you have yet to fully test your code against 2008r2). This will save you needing to test your application against a new version again when 2008r2 falls out of support and gives you access to 2012's nice additions (lag and lead window functions which can make certain report type queries massively more efficient, and so forth) should you need them.

Answer (score 2):

That does not matter. When you upgrade an existing instance with a database attached SQL Server automatically upgrades the database too. If you attach the database after the upgrade, it goes through the same process.

In either case make sure that the database is at the right compatibility level. While usually nothing happens, you might run into problems if the database is still at 80. Changing the compatibility level however will change behavior, so make sure you test you application well.